# How to create a setting for a simple wordpress plugin?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I've created this simple plugin and it removes admin links menu from admin panel.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: admin menu remover
Description: Remove the admin menus just by a single plugin installation
Version: 1.0
Author: Author
Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/

function remove_links_menu() {
     remove_menu_page('index.php'); // Dashboard    
     remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php'); // Comments
     remove_menu_page('themes.php'); // Appearance
     //remove_menu_page('plugins.php'); // Plugins     
     remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Tools
     remove_menu_page('options-general.php'); // Settings
     remove_menu_page('users.php'); // Users
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_links_menu' );
?>
```

It removes 6 menus instantly after the installation. 1 line (plugins) is commented out.
Now I want to add setting option to the plugin where the user would be able to select which menu should be removed.
There should be a check box on the plugin setting where we can select which menu should be shown and hidden.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the options in the _options table using [update_option( $option, $new_value )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)
then you can use [get_option( $option, $default )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to read the value from the database.
You'll have to be a little carefull when naming your option so it won't conflict with other options names (use of a prefix should fix this)